# How to pause one node while a specific argument (rostopic) is active

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Need suggestions to pause a face tracking system when a specific argument from another topic is active. The current code is written in python.

Example of what I want to do:

```
while (rostopic /robotsound/arg != "/home/user/workspace/audio/resources/good_audio.wav")
     face_track_system()
```

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60234/how-to-pause-one-node-while-a-specific-argument-(rostopic)-is-active/) by [amrivera](https://answers.ros.org/users/3700/amrivera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amrivera](https://answers.ros.org/users/3700/amrivera/) on 2013-04-10**:
Please close this question, as I don't have sufficient permission. dornhege's idea worked. Thanks all

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-10**:
We don't need to close the question, you just need to accept his answer by clicking the check mark below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just subscribe the topic and set a flag to call face_track_system() in your code depending on that value.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2